# Why does it take very long to start downloading from the playstore?

Tags: google-play-store

It typically take from 5 minutes to hours after I tap on download or update in playstore. Sometimes I can activate downloading process by opening up Google map or Google assistant.

Comment: Can you explain the last part?

Comment: 1. Is your internet speed fine ? Maybe you are using a VPN to access Store and that is throttling the speed. Is your download fine on other sites? 2. Settings > apps> show system> download manager > storage > clear data and cache. See if that helps

Answer (score -1):

You have not mentioned how you are connected to **Playstore**. Example Wifi, Broadband or Wifi through a Tether. Its too general a question.

The most common reason in this case is due to the network condition. Try to install at different time of the day. Switch to different networking environment and see the difference.

Comment: I don't think Tboxmy can leave a comment so this is really the only option he has to respond.